# I don't understand output of my method while recursively calculating powers

Tags: java, recursion

I don't see how this method would be used 31 times when I try to recursively calculate 2^8.

Does this method calculate powers in O(logN) complexity?

When I run it the output is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
...
29
30
2^8 is: 256
```

Code

```
private static int power(int x, int y)
{
    System.out.println(step++);

    if (y == 0)
        return 1;

    return power(x, y/2) * power(x, y/2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you're actually making two calls to the power method with the same values:

```
return power(x, y/2) * power(x, y/2);
```

Instead, you could make half as many calls if you write it like this:

```
int toReturn = power(x, y/2);
return toReturn * toReturn;
```

If we walk through your original example, we will make 31 calls, which is what you see (0 to 30).  Walk through your code to see why:

```
power(2, 8)

power(2, 4)
power(2, 4)

power(2, 2)
power(2, 2)
power(2, 2)
power(2, 2)

power(2, 1)
power(2, 1)
power(2, 1)
power(2, 1)
power(2, 1)
power(2, 1)
power(2, 1)
power(2, 1)

power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
power(2, 0)
```

Comment: I tried that, I keep getting error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at risingPowers.power(risingPowers.java:14)`

Comment: But isnt creating a variable increasing the `space complexity` ? I mean there is always a trade-off between the two ?

Comment: @HelpNeeder  `StackOverflow-error on a suggestion on StackOverflow`, Ironic.. :D haha;  can you tell which line is `14` as per your workspace? @Cory Kendall No offense #peace

Comment: The line with: `int toReturn = power(x, y/2);`.

Comment: Never mind. I need to search for 0 value before I assign value to this. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @HelpNeeder i guesss `0` and `negatives` will give you that error. a `validateInput` function should do

Answer (score 2):

As the other posters have pointed out, you're calling the `power` method too often. I just would like to add (and I don't want to do this as a comment) that I do not recommend the use of a static variable to count the levels of recursion. Instead, I'd recommend to pass the current step as another parameter to the function:

```
private static int power(int x, int y, int recursiveCallStep)
{
    System.out.println(recursiveCallStep++);

    if (y == 0)
        return 1;

    int toReturn = power(x, y/2, recursiveCallStep);
    return toReturn * toReturn;
}
```

The first call would then be:

```
int result = power(2, 8, 0);
```

Had you done this before, you'd have realised that the same step-number is output more than once.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not O(logN), it is O(NlogN)

At each iteration, you are creating problems that have half the size of the problem (that is good) but you are creating **two of them**.

You should do, instead of

```
 return power(x, y/2) * power(x, y/2);
```

this

```
 int power = power(x, y/2);
 return power * power;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no need for a divide-et-impera tree. That's why your code is recomputing more than once the same values.

You gain much better complexity with this simpler recursive code: (you can see that it is O(N))

```
private static int power(int x, int y)
{
    System.out.println(step++);

    if (y == 0)
        return 1;
    else
    {
        return x * power(x, y - 1);
    }
}
```

With X = 2 and Y = 3 the stack trace would be:

```
power(2,3) = 2 * power(2, 2);
power(2,2) = 2 * power(2, 1);
power(2,1) = 2 * power(2, 0);
power(2,0) = 1;
```